# How to statically link a library which links dynamically another library?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have the following situation in using *GCC*:
[image: Situation]

I have a **dynamic** library named **A.DLL**  which compiles and links correctly and generates **LIBA.A**.

Now, I have another **static** library named **LIBB.A** which has a function definition that uses `afunc()` from **A.DLL**. This also compiles and links correctly and generates **LIBB.A**.

However when I am using **LIBB.A** in another program **PROGC.C** to compile to the executable program **PROGC.EXE**, *GCC* cannot link to **A.DLL**  using **LIBA.A**.

It gives the error: `undefined reference to afunc()`.

I tried doing kind of the following:

```
 gcc PROGC.C -o PROGC.EXE -lLIBB.A -Wl,-Bdynamic -lLIBA.A ...
```

But nothing is working to link successfully.

My question is whether this is possible at all? If yes, how to do this? If no, why it is not?

(Thanks in advance.)

Comment: maybe you are not using the same calling convention!!!

Comment: How did you build your libb.a?

Comment: @jdarthenay I am using the following to build libb.a: `gcc.exe ... -c B.c -o B.o` and `ar.exe -r -s LIBB.A  B.o `. However, as asked by @milevyo, I am not using any explicit calling convention in any of the libraries. Is this a problem? P.S. I am building everything using the same compiler.

Comment: Were you successful to link a program to a.dll only? (no libb).

Comment: Yes! Another similar example in my case was where **A.dll** was pre-compiled **opengl32.dll** and **libb.a** was a static library which has a single function definition using `opengl draw functions` and only when I was using that particular function from **libb.a**, I was getting the same linking error. But I was always able to dynamically link **opengl32**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example doing who you try to do:

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#ifdef BUILD_A_DLL
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

extern EXPORT void __cdecl print_a_version();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

a.c:

```
#define BUILD_A_DLL

#include "a.h"

#include <stdio.h>

EXPORT void __cdecl print_a_version()
{
    printf("A: v1.0\n");
}
```

b.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

extern void print_b_version();

#endif
```

b.c:

```
#include "b.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include "a.h"

void print_b_version()
{
    print_a_version();
    printf("B: v1.0\n");
}
```

stackoverflow.c:

```
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    print_b_version();

    return 0;
}
```

makefile (for mingw-64):

```
CC=GCC
AR=ar
WINVER=0x0400
CFLAGS=-Wformat -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror -DWINVER=$(WINVER) -std=gnu99
LDFLAGSDLL=-shared -Wl,--out-implib,liba.a
LDFLAGS=-L. -lb -la

all:a.dll libb.a stackoverflow.exe

a.dll:a.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o a.dll a.o $(LDFLAGSDLL)

a.o:a.c a.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c a.c

libb.a:b.o
    $(AR) -rs libb.a b.o

b.o:b.c b.h a.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c b.c

stackoverflow.exe:stackoverflow.o libb.a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o stackoverflow.exe stackoverflow.o $(LDFLAGS)

stackoverflow.o:stackoverflow.c b.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c stackoverflow.c

mrproper:clean
    for %%i in (a.dll liba.dll libb.o stackoverflow.exe) do if exist %%i del %%i

clean:
    for %%i in (a.o b.o stackoverflow.o) do if exist %%i del %%i

.PHONY:all clean mrproper
```

This works for me.

Edit: Important note - the order of `-l` flags is very important. With `LDFLAGS=-L. -la -lb` building "stackoverflow.exe" fails.

Comment: I see my mistake was in the order of linking because there were other libraries also.